# Function that returns value and provides access to inside-defined methods

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How to have global object `myLib` to be, at the same time, library-style function that takes parameters and returns boolean value (true/false) and, let's call it container for other, publicly accessible methods, like this:

```
window.myLib = (function(w){

    //...
    function on(arg, callback){
    }

    return function(arg1, arg2){
        //returns true or false, based on calculation on arg1, arg2...
    }

})(window)        

myLib('something', 'somethingother')// will return true or false        
myLib.on('somecondition', function(){})// note the on() method-that's what I'm trying to accomplish
```

or should I ask, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in javascript are objects, so you can actually add methods to them. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

```
window.myLib = (function(window){
    function myLib(a, b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    }

    myLib.method1 = function (a) {
        console.log(a);
    }

    myLib.method2 = function (a, b) {
        console.log(a + b);
    }

    return myLib;

})(window);
```

And now you can use both the function, and attached methods:

`myLib(1, 2);`

`myLib.method1(5);`

`myLib.method2(5, 3);`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible like this

```
window.myLib = (function(w){

    //...
    function on(arg, callback){
    }

    function main(arg1, arg2){ // main is an arbitrary name with no significance
        //returns true or false, based on calculation on arg1, arg2...
    }
    main.on = on;
    return main;

})(window)
```